# How can I scale an xpm image, retaining symbolic colour names

Tags: image-processing, command-line, scaling

I'm trying to batch scale a load of xpm images to double pixel size. I can do this using ImageMagick like this:

```
convert infile.xpm -sample 200% outfile.xpm
```

However, the symbolic colour names are lost.

In the original input, the colour entries are as follows:

```
".  c #007EBF s active_hilight_1",
"+  c #0A5E89 s active_color_1",
"@  c #143D52 s active_shadow_1",
```

In the up-scaled version:

```
"  c #143D52",
". c #0A5E89",
"X c #007EBF",
```

The colour names changed, which is fine, but as you can see the `s <symbolic-name>` suffixes are stripped.

Does anyone know a quick way to do this using ImageMagick or a similar (open-source) utility?

Thanks

EDIT: Seems ImageMagick can't due this due to a bug, but does anyone know any other tool which may be able to do this?

Comment: What version of ImageMagick and platform are you using? Can you post a link to your XPM file?  Which XPM format is it? Perhaps ImageMagick is writing to simpler version of XPM? Or since it is a new image, perhaps it is not copying the symbolic names? You could report it as a bug on the ImageMagick forum or Git repository.  https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick or https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/.

Comment: Hi fmw42. I'm using ImageMagick-6.9.10.61 on OpenBSD. The images I want to scale are part of an xfce window manager theme. I'm trying to double-scale the theme for HDPI displays. The images are in git here: https://git.xfce.org/archive/xfwm4-themes/tree/themes/mofit . I also tried using `mogrify` instead of `convert` which also stripped the symbolic names. Happy to raise a bug upstream if there's really no way to pass the names through.

Comment: I also just built ImageMagick master to see if it had been fixed there. No joy.

Comment: I know little about XPM format. I tried to download a file and just got ascii text. So I pasted that into a text file called test.xpm. But ImageMagick would not read it. What do I have to do to get one of your files in a form that ImageMagick will recognize? Can you zip one and put a link to it? Otherwise, just report that as a bug on one of the ImageMagick forums or GIT repository.

Comment: Finally got it to process. I had to change the suffix from xpm to just pm as hinted at https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php. But it does lose the first characters and the s characters. So I would suggest you report that to ImageMagick as bugs in both regards. It should be keeping the structure, I would think, and also should recognize the .xpm suffix as well as .pm suffix.

Comment: Odd that the xpm wouldn't load. I didn't have to rename anything on my system. Did you trying cloning from git, in case it was to do with the copy/paste? Will report a bug upstream for the name losses. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/1684

Comment: Yes, I saw that and the response was that they could reproduce it and would fix it for the next release.

Comment: I was impressed with how quickly they fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mogrify -sample 200% *.xpm
```

^ This  works as long as you have a new (post 2019-09-02) version of ImageMagick with the xpm output bug fixed, as described here:
https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/1684

Today's master branch, for example, passes symbolic colour names through properly.